# Javascript scoping issue with jQuery validate

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-validate

I am having an issue with the 'sync' variable in the function below sticking once it's set the first time.

If I call the below with...

```
save(true);
save(false);
```

.

```
    var save = function (sync) {

        // value of sync here always reflects what is passed in

        $('form').validate({
            rules: {
                ...
            },
            submitHandler: function () {
                var ajax = sync;  // the first time sync is true, and then it is always true!
            }
        });
        $('form').submit();
    }
```

The first call sync is 'true'.  On the second call sync is 'false' before the validate, but in the submitHandler, sync is back to 'true'.

I think this is a scoping issue.  In the submit handler how can I access the passed in value of 'sync'?

Comment: Each time you call `save` you are creating a new validator object without removing the old one. Can you add more of the code around how `save` is getting called? Ideally you should only be calling `$().validate()` __once__ no matter how many times you call `save`.

Comment: save() gets called straight from a button click handler.  So click the button, and save gets called (and is only called once).  I think 'this' in the submitHandler is jquery validate itself.  Somehow once sync gets set it never can be set again.  Very strange.

Comment: ...it sounds like you're doing it wrong then. You should call `validate` on the form when it's created, and let it handle the submit events. What is the purpose of `save(false)`?

Comment: What I mean to say is that, while you do having a scoping problem here, the problem is a symptom of misusing the library. You should fix the root cause, not the symptom.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.  I have it working properly now after re-factoring the code to not rely on a sync variable.

Comment: You are definitely doing it wrong because you may not realize the `.validate()` method is only designed to initialize the plugin. You are not supposed to call it repeatedly such as would happen when it's triggered by a click or submit handler or inside of another function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this issue by using jQuery validate properly.  As suggested by @Mathletics, I now call validate upon initialization and use Valid() to validate the form.